# Vector spaces as bimodules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

The usual definition of a vector space $V$ over $K$ is as an abelian group, on which $(K\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ acts on the left, such that furthermore the operation of $K$ on $V$ is compatible with the addition, i.e. we have $k\cdot (u + v) = k\cdot u + k\cdot v$ and also $(k + s)\cdot u = k\cdot u + s\cdot u$.

Now with the definition $u\cdot k := k\cdot u$ we have a right action (for which commutativity of $(K\setminus\{0\}, \cdot)$ is essential, as $u(ks) = (ks)u = (sk)u = s(ku) = s(uk) = (uk)s$), which makes $V$ into an [$K-K$-bimodule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodule) as $(ku)s = s(ku) = (sk)u = (ks)u = k(su) = k(us)$.

> But does there exists a vector space $V$, which has two different action of some field $K$ on $V$ which are not compatible, i.e. the order of application of two different elements matter, or equivalently does there exists a vector space, on which $K$ acts also on the right with similar laws, such that $V$ is not a $K$-$K$-bimodule w.r.t. to both actions?

Answer (score 1):

Check my profile for my dissertation, you'll find an example. Specifically, let $G$ be a group, $V$ a vector space on which $G$ acts on the left, and $F(V)$ the field of fractions of the symmetric algebra of $V$. Define a ring $R$ to be the left $F(V)$-vector space with basis $G$ with right action given by (for $g\in G$, $f\in F(V)$)
$$gf=(g\cdot f)g$$
Multiplication of elements of $G$ uses the product in $G$. $R$ is called a "skew group ring" of $G$ over $F(V)$ because it's the group ring twisted by an action on the coefficient ring.

Here the actions are compatible in the sense that $R$ is indeed a bimodule, but the left and right actions are different.

For an example, let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be a basis for a vector space, and let the symmetric group $S_n$ (the set of bijective functions from $[n]$ to itself) act by $w\cdot x_i=x_{w(i)}$. $S_n$ acts on the field of fractions in these indeterminates by, for example, 
$$w\cdot \frac1{x_i-x_j}=\frac1{x_{w(i)}-x_{w(j)}}$$
Then in our ring $R$ (which is not the module coefficient ring, which is $F(V)$, but rather the module) which contains $F(V)$ as a subring, has an action of $F(V)$ by right and left multiplication, where, for example,
$$wx_i=x_{w(i)}w$$

Comment: I am not sure about your example. 1) How does $G$ acts on $F(V)$?, 2) Assume we know how it acts, then how does your definition of the right action works? If $r \in R$, where $r = \sum_g a_g g$, and $g \in G$ we need to define $r\cdot g$, but you write $gf$, as if $F(V)$ acts on $G$ on the right? Could you maybe expand your answer a little bit?

Comment: @Stefan Maybe later today. I'd say look at my dissertation, but one of the complaints the outside member of the committee had was that there were no examples, so this could be where I put one!

Comment: @Stefan hope the example helps.